# How to avoid getting a negative value?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to be able to avoid getting a negative value. I need the datagrid to shrink when window browser is resized but not reaching a negative value to avoid getting error. Is that possible? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
public SilverlightResizeTest() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        // Set the height for the DataGrid when the browser window changes size  
        App.Current.Host.Content.Resized += new System.EventHandler(Content_Resized); 

        // Set the initial height for the DataGrid 
        double x = App.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight; 
        if (x != 0) 
        { 
            DataGrid.Height = (x - 485.0); 
        } 
    } 

    void Content_Resized(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Set the height for the DataGrid when the browser window changes size 
        double x = App.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight; 
        if (x != 0) 
        { 
            DataGrid.Height = (x - 485.0); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DataGrid.Height = Math.Max(0.0, x - 485.0);
```

Comment: It works great. Thank you for the help! I highly appreaciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Either this

```
DataGrid.Height = Math.Max(0, x - 485.0);
```

or this

```
DataGrid.Height = (x - 485.0);
if(DataGrid.Height < 0) DataGrid.Height = 0;
```

or ...

Really, there are tons of ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, onn Content_Resized method

```
DataGrid.Height = x > (485.0) ? (x - 485.0) : DataGrid.Height;
```

this way if the new Height would be 0, it instead keeps the previous height, also you can define a minimum height four your data grid: and use this line instead:

```
DataGrid.Height = x > (485.0 + minHeight) ? (x - 485.0) : DataGrid.Height;
```

Answer (score 1):

why not check for it? :

```
 DataGrid.Height = Math.Max(0 , x - 485.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DataGrid.Height = Math.Max((x - 485.0), 0.0);
```

Comment: It works great. Actually all of the suggested ways to achieve it works for me. Thank you all for the help! I highly appreaciate it.